# Why does unplugging my laptop from power reduce power consumption?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, power-management, energy-saving

I want to save unneeded energy. Because of that, I changed my energy settings to power save mode.

However, once I switch off the power supply for my laptop, the energy consumption and CPU tact goes downwards *even more*. You can hear that by the ventilation getting quieter.

I went into *energy options* -> *energy plan settings* -> *advanced energy settings* and made sure there are no differences at all between battery mode and power supply operation in energy save mode. Did not do any difference; the CPU performance still increases if I attach power to my laptop.

Why is that? How can I actually enjoy the exact same power saving management with power supply being active?

Toshiba Satellite series

Comment: If you are trying to save the planet, this is like holding your breath to reduce your carbon footprint.  Using your computer requires a certain amount of energy whether you use it "live" from the adapter or use it to charge the battery and then use it from there.  The difference in actual power usage is insignificant in the scheme of things.  The power saver settings are there to stretch how long you can operate on a battery charge.  Many laptops can achieve reasonable run times only if they cut back on performance when you run from the battery.

Comment: that's right, but no reason to accept window's arbitrariness.

Comment: also, it's not my intend to save the planet, but not to pay for  unnecessary energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you may be mis-interpreting things or it might be the way the user interface is presenting power information to you is misleading.

Plugging in AC power should not suddenly make your CPU start drawing more power, that would just be silly. But the GUI may simply be indicating to you that, with AC plugged in, your *potential* CPU performance is higher should you require it.

As for the ventilation going while AC is plugged in, that's almost certainly due to the battery charging (charging causes lots of heat to be generated which in turn can cause the laptop's fans to turn up a bit).

The other thing to look for is some kind of hidden advanced power settings especially within Toshiba's own Power application, whatever it's called. Toshiba's own application will have far richer configuration than what you find in Windows' control panel.